# How do I paint an always-on-top green circle on my macOS display?

Tags: macos, paint, always-on-top

How do I create a program that paints an always-on-top small green circle on my screen?

Is it possible in AppleScript, Python or Java? Is Swift or Objective-C needed? Solutions in all programming languages are most welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple to create a macOS menu bar app using Python, [Rumps](https://github.com/jaredks/rumps), and [py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

[This guide](https://camillovisini.com/article/create-macos-menu-bar-app-pomodoro/) explains the basics, which is basically:

```
import rumps

class GreenCircleApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = rumps.App("GreenCircle", "")

    def run(self):
        self.app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = GreenCircleApp()
    app.run()
```

The circle can easily be changed using e.g. `self.app.title = ""`